# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound (WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This error I am getting in Tomcat server:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestProject/user/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ravi'

I am getting the above error my I am redirecting to the register page.

My web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ravi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ravi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My ravi-servlet.xml

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.webProject" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
```

My controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/TestProject/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newEmployeeForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("User Registration" , "User Registration");
        return "register";
    }
```

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure you have register.jsp in WEB-INF/view? If yes please ensure the controller class is in the `context:component-scan` package

Comment: Yes my jsp is in under web-inf/ view/user/register.jsp and also the controller is in the component-scan package

Comment: Okay, then you have to return `"user/register"` from the controller

Comment: This approach "user/register " also I have used same error.

Comment: That's strange, possible to post you complete codebase?

Answer (score 0):

Just update `<url-pattern>` from `/` to `/*` and also update `<servlet>` by adding your custom `ravi-servlet.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ravi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ravi-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ravi</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Note : Keep all your jsp pages in `/WEB-INF/view/` directory of your project.

Comment: @ravi what is happening after you have updated web.xml with my configuration ?

Comment: Home page itself it is not calling while running the server.

Comment: @ravi This configuration will definitely work. I suggest that you create a new project from scratch and check whether it's working or not.